# How to extract time field from date field and displaying it as AM/PM

Tags: datetime

In DATA TIME field,how to exact time field and how to display it in AM OR PM format.

for example this is:

```
                  startdate--> 2018-06-03 19:00:00
                  Enddate-->  2018-06-03 19:30:00
```

I have to extract time field in Apex controller.I have to display it as
7PM - 7.30PM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to get the time in 12 hour format.

You can use `datetime` `format` method for this. For example,

```
startdate.format('HH:mm a')
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to display the month of the date like "march27"